# How to delete records without generating redo log

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I have a table like following:

```
Create Table Txn_History nologging (
ID number,
Comment varchar2(300),
... (Another 20 columns),
Std_hash raw(1000) 
);
```

This table is 8GB with 19 Million rows with a growth of around 50,000 rows daily.

I need to delete 300,000 rows and update 100,000 rows. I know that normally delete and update statement will cause Oracle database to generate redo log. The only way I know to avoid this is to create a new table with the updated result.

However, consider that the delete and update statement is only talking about 2% of the entire table, it appears not very worth to create a new table, follow by all corresponding indexes.

Do you have any new idea?

Comment: There are too much dimensions to measure "better" approach. What do you want to achieve/avoid? redo is not what takes much resources. Update of couple of percents rows is a normal process, you just need to execute it as fast as possible

Comment: Agree with others the redo should not be a problem. Also, it is unavoidable in almost all cases anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I don't think that the redo generation is a big problem here: just 300k rows to delete and 100k rows to update... For such batch operations Oracle uses fast "array update" REDO operation. Probably you need to trace your operation to find out real bottlenecks and load profile(IO/CPU, access paths, triggers, indexes, etc).

Basically it's better to use the partitioning option properly to update/delete(or truncate) by whole partitions.

There is also new `alter table ... move including rows where ...` feature starting from Oracle 12.2:
https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-delete-millions-of-rows-fast-with-sql

Comment: Hi Sayan, Thank you for your advise and also the link you shared. I will try to get some insight from there.